# Is there a way to Dynamically update gridview values on JOINED queries?

Tags: vb.net

I am building a Query builder.Therefore I have different kinds of queries to run and display the result on a Gridview.I was able to update the database with Grid Changes by using the commandbuilder class.The problem is that Icannot update using commandbuilder when i'm using joint queries.I cannot explicictly specify the update query for the select statement since i'm using different queries.I need a dynamic way of updating a gridview from a joined query.

I have tried assigning the specific datatable row  to new data and accepting the datatable changes using datatable.AcceptChanges()

```
Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
    Try
        If Not qry.Contains("JOIN") Then
            Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(adpt)
            adpt.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(qry, con)
            adpt.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
            adpt.Update(dataTable)

        Else
            'TODO : Update GridView Without using QueryBuilder(Dynamically)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for the pasted code:It should be      Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        Try
            If Not qry.Contains("JOIN") Then
                Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(adpt)
                adpt.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(qry, con)
                adpt.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand()
                adpt.Update(dataTable)

            Else
                'Up








            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        con.Close()
    End Sub

Comment: Code in comments is even harder to read.  Take notice of the preview and don't submit unless the question looks right.  If you make a mistake, edit.

Comment: Why do you think that you can't use a command builder in the first place?  It's because there's no easy way to determine exactly what needs to be updated.  Now you're asking to tell you how to know what needs to be updated.  There's no magic way to do it.  You have analyse the SQL in the query yourself.  Get used to the fact that the easier things are for the user, the more difficult they are for the developer.  Basically, you're almost certainly not at a point where what you want to do is a realistic possibility.  It would be difficult even for someone experienced.

Comment: Commandbuilder only works for single tables.And The passed in queries are different for every user.I needed a way to separate joined queries into select statements dynamically

Comment: There is no magic way to do that.  It's up to you to parse the SQL and analyse it. If you don't now how to parse structured text, that's what you need to research.  As it stands, that question is too broad for this site.